# How to automatically create a default constructor which sets default values

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Is there any way to auto generate a constructor which looks like this:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        Id = 0;
        Name = "";
    }
}
```

Currently I am creating a constructor like that with the refactoring tool (CTRL + .):

```
    public User(int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }
```

and after removing the parameters, editing each line afterwards which is pretty cumbersome when you have 20 properties per class. Is there a better way to that?
(Maybe to define a code snippet, so that we can somehow read the class properties with reflection and define them as snippet parameters?)

Comment: ReSharper has a initialize from constructor option. ...but that is a paid VS extension.

Comment: You're asking for a constructor that takes two parameters named similarly to the properties of the class, *ignores* those parameters and sets the properties to default values instead? How on earth is that the norm in your code base?

Comment: @musium, please write your comment as an answer that I can accept as the correct answer.

Comment: @Housheng-MSFT: I already added a comment for the comment of Damien_The_Unbeliever. If he writes his comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a class with 20 properties, why do you need a constructor with 20 parameters? Maybe have a sense, but I usually create constructors to initialize properties that are relevant, to simplify the code, not to set all properties.

For your class, you can set the default values when you define the property and all constructors will use this values as the default.

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; } = 0;
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    // Here you can even omit the constructor
    public User()
    {
    }
}
```

Another thing that maybe useful is define a constructor with X parameters and reuse this constructor in other constructors with less parameters:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public User()
        : this(0, string.Empty)
    {
    }

    public User(int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

You can replace `this(0, string.Empty)` for `this(default, default)` if you want use the default value of each type.

Answer (score 0):

If you need object create with default value for properties. You can code like this:

```cs
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; } = 0;
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
}
```

Purpose of quick action "generate constructor" make method contructor for assign value to fields or properties. Don't use it in the case of just assigning default values.

Answer (score -1):

do you mean initialize properties? Initializing properties through the code reflection mechanism also requires one-by-one assignments. For private object properties, it is necessary to de-private encapsulation. The operation of initializing properties in c# is generally to initialize object properties or object initializers in the form of constructors. Thank you hope it helps you

```
 class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Student student = new Student()
        {
            age = 25,
            name = "java",
            sex = "female"
        };
    }
   class Student
    {
        public int age { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string sex { get; set; }
        public Student()
        {

        }
        public Student(int age, string name,string sex)
        {
            this.age = age;
            this.name = name;
            this.sex = sex;
        }
    }

}
```